# Marcador esta duplicando ao atualizar Localizacao do Usuario

Tags: android, google-maps

Implementei a activity de Localizacao do Uusuario a cada 15 segundos.

As variaveis são globais da classe:

latitudeUsuario
longitudeUsuario
marker

Dentro do método `onLocationChanged` eu seto as duas variáveis de localizacao, e chamo o adicionarMarcadores .

```
private void adicionarMarcadores() {

        if(marker != null){
            marker.remove();

        }

        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeUsuario, longitudeUsuario)).title("Minhaaa"));
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-23.618439,-46.605477)).title("Userss12"));


       mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitudeUsuario, longitudeUsuario), 18.0f));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
```

O problema é que o `"Userss12"` por ser uma localização estática esta somente com um Marcador, até ai tudo bem.

Mas o `"Minhaaa"` está repetindo o Marcador sempre que atualiza!

deixando um monte de marcador no mapa....

Comment: tente usar mMap.clear() vai limpar tudo que estiver no mapa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ocorre o seguinte:

Ao invocar o `marker.remove();` remove apenas a última referencia!

Para resolver, crie dois marker's:

```
if(markerUm != null){
        markerUm.remove();
 }
if(markerDois != null){
        markerDois.remove();
 }

 markerUm = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeUsuario, longitudeUsuario)).title("Minhaaa"));
 markerDois = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-23.618439,-46.605477)).title("Userss12"));
```

Comment: Thiago, o problema era que as variaveis globais, sempre mantinham os marcadores. Nao da para eu criar somente dois , porque serão varios, conforme estiverem num raio de 3km.

Comment: Então use uma **List<Marker>** e remova através de um for

Comment: Boa...deu certo...